# How to put 2 Facebook fan page like box on one page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Is it possible to put two Facebook fan page like boxes on the same page?

And if so, how do I do it.

I'm able to put one but not more - is it a js problem? would iFrame work?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about the social plugin: like button ? and with fan page i assume an application running in a Facebook Page tab? if soo you can just add as many like buttons as you want...

Comment: yes I'm talking about the social plugin. so I can put a like box to https://facebook.com/page1 and  https://facebook.com/page2 on the same url http://example.com?

Comment: sure! , i prefer using javascript to add any like button... use fb.xfbml.parse http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/ just add the like button code to a div, and parse the div ... you'll get an event when it's loaded so you can like fade in the button or some some

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add as many [Like](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) buttons as you want by just providing the value for attribute `href` within the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page. If not specified it defaults to current page.